# Usage of the future perfect tense: "... a year will have completed..." Is it correct?

Tags: future, future-perfect

Is the following sentence correct?

> By the end of September, a year will have completed for our friendship.

Comment: What earthly point is there in simply downvoting something without leaving any comment?

Comment: Absolutely none. One of my pet hates on [ubuntu.se]... Okay, so it isn't an amazing question, but there isn't anything wrong. +1

Comment: Possibly the downvote is for the question being "off-topic", it is a "proof reading" question, and the OP doesn't appear to be interested in the slightest as to why the phrase "doesn't work". A comment explaining that would have been courteous, and might have lead to a *better* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.

> "*for our friendship*"

doesn't work, although I can't put my finger on what is wrong.

Much simpler, and correct:

> At the end of September, we will have been friends for a year